# Not allowed to load local resource a href

Tags: resources, load, local

I have following code :
The files are on O drive resides on server.
Using normal html tag a with href .

[Click here to see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehD8I.jpg)

But getting Error in browser console :
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///O:/Appdata/rfms/Ref_Docs/Refinery%20East/RDS/Unit%20081/FER/TSS%20Scanned%20Documents/C-1232/C-8110%20CERTIFICATE%20%20OF%20SHOP%20COMPLIANCE%2002-17-12.PDF

I have tried many solutions like window.open , --allow-file-access-from-files in chrome . But nothing working for me. The application is in ASP.NET MVC